# delete using stored proc in mysql drops entire table

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench, sql-delete

I have a stored proc which has only 1 line in it to delete a record in a table given a condition. 
When I call the storedproc using 'CALL storedprocname('2');', it deletes all records from the table i.e. truncates. I have run the delete statement independently and it works fine, deleting only specified record. Am I missing something? 
(I am using mysqlworkbench on macosx)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS usp_DeleteCompany;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteCompany (IN CompanyId VARCHAR(3))
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Company WHERE CompanyId = (CAST(CompanyId AS UNSIGNED));
-- DELETE FROM Company WHERE CompanyId = (CAST('2' AS UNSIGNED))
END; $$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not pass the parameter as `unsigned` directly like `IN CompanyId UNSIGNED`? no need of casting it then.

Also, consider changing the parameter name to something different than the actual column name `CompanyId`.

To me it seems like your `delete` query below

```
DELETE FROM Company WHERE CompanyId = (CAST(CompanyId AS UNSIGNED));
```

getting converted to below cause it's considering `CompanyId` as the exact column of the table instead of the actual parameter passed to the procedureand so end up deleting all rows.

```
DELETE FROM Company WHERE CompanyId = CompanyId;
```

Consider using a different name for the parameter like `Cid` in your query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_DeleteCompany (IN Cid UNSIGNED)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Company WHERE CompanyId = Cid;
END;
```